# anchor tag doesn't work within div with :before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have a code something like this

```
<div class="container">
   <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

where I use the pseudo element `::before` in container to set a background image with opacity for the container div. However, when I set the background image using the `::before` pseudo element, I cannot click on the anchor tag, and when I remove the pseudo element, it works fine. How can I go around this issue by keeping the background image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `pointer-events: none` on the pseudo to let clicks pass through it.